# Visual Studio 2019 does not recognize tsconfig.json

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I just installed Visual Studio 2019 and tried it with my current solution. It seems like it ignores the `tsconfig.json` file, while it worked in VS 2017.
In Visual Studio 2017 in project properties: TypeScript Build, it shows:

> One or more tsconfig.json or jsconfig.json files detected. Project properties are disabled.

[image]

This works good and compiles the files according to my `tsconfig.json` file.

Now the newly installed Visual Studio 2019 behaves differently. It does not show that sentence and I have to configure all the settings in the project properties. It seems like it does not recognize my `tsconfig.json` file at all.

How do I get VS 2019 to use the `tsconfig.json` instead of the project properties?

Comment: Make sure VS2019 has all of the needed components installed?

Comment: @Amy What special components does VS2019 need for TypeScript?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The Build Action property (F4) for the `tsconfig.json` file has to be set to `Content`.
Otherwise Visual Studio ignores this file since VS 2019.

There is a downside though: After this change VS 2017 will complain about the Build Action:

> Error
> NETSDK1022
>
> Duplicate 'Content' items were included. The .NET SDK includes
> 'Content' items from your project directory by default. You can either
> remove these items from your project file, or set the
> 'EnableDefaultContentItems' property to 'false' if you want to
> explicitly include them in your project file. For more information,
> see https://aka.ms/sdkimplicititems. The duplicate items were:
> 'tsconfig.json'

Comment: Spent 2 days trying to figure this out and then I stumbled across this amazing solution. I am using VS 2022 with ReactJS and could not get errors to resolve until I made the file content. Thank you

Comment: I went through a deep rabbit hole of non-solutions after trying to add the `@types/web` package in VS. This was all I had to do.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone comes here because Visual Studio 2019 builder seems to ignore the `exclude` section of `tsconfig.json`, you can invert the filters and use an `include` section instead, that works

VS2019 tsconfig.json Example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/compile-typescript-code-npm?view=vs-2019